# Check if the function of two variables is continuous by definition of continuity

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

I need to check if this function is continuous.

$f(x,y) = \frac{\sin x + \sin y}{x+y}$.

So I can see that the problem points are [0,0] and all the points where x=-y.

But let's suppose that we know that the function is continuous in $a = (x_{0},y_{0})$ if

$\forall \varepsilon>0$  $\exists \delta>0 \left \| x - a \right \| < \delta  \Rightarrow \left \| f(x)-f(a) \right \| < \varepsilon $.

So if we take the point [-y,y] we will get $\sqrt{(x+y)^{2}}<\delta$ ,

$x+y<\delta $

I've noticed that I can simplify the function as

$\frac{\sin (\frac{x+y}{2})\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})} {\frac{x+y}{2}}$

and

$\lim_{x+y\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin (\frac{x+y}{2})} {\frac{x+y}{2}} = 1$

So I've got $\cos (\frac{x-y}{2})$ but I don't know what to do next. How can I find a $\delta $ for every $\varepsilon $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and consider $u = (-y,y)$ for some $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider a sequence $u_n = (x_n, y_n)$ such that $u_n \to u$. 
Using your reformulation, we have that $f(u_n) = \frac{\sin(
\frac{x_n+y_n}{2})}{\frac{x_n+y_n}{2}}\cos(\frac{x_n-y_n}{2})$.
We will prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(u_n) = \cos(y)$. This is true if $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $n_0 > 0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$, $| f(u_n) - \cos(y)| < \varepsilon$.

Since $u_n \to u$, for every $\delta > 0$, there exists $n_0$ such that $\|u_n - u\| = \sqrt{x_n^2 + y_n^2} < \delta$.  We assume known, that $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t} = 1$. Hence, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |t| < 2\delta \Rightarrow |\frac{\sin(t)}{t}-1| < \varepsilon/2$.  Now, we have that $|x_n + y_n| \leq |x_n| + |y_n| \leq \sqrt{x_n^2+y_n^2} + \sqrt{x_n^2 + y_n^2} = 2 \sqrt{x_n^2 + y_n^2} < 2 \delta$ from what follows that $\frac{\sin(x_n+y_n)}{x_n+y_n}\cos(\frac{x_n-y_n}{2})-\cos(\frac{x_n-y_n}{2})| < \varepsilon/2$

By continuity of the $\cos$ function, there exists a $n_1 > 0$ such that $\forall n \geq n_1, |\cos(\frac{x_n-y_n}{2}) - \cos(y)| < \varepsilon/2$. Putting everything together, we have that, for all $n \geq n' := \max\{n_0,n_1\}$, $$|f(u_n) - \cos(y)| = |f(u_n) - \cos(\frac{x_n-y_n}{2}) + \cos(\frac{x_n-y_n}{2}) - \cos(y)| \leq \varepsilon /2 + \varepsilon / 2  = \varepsilon.$$

Comment: note that there is no need to use sequences, and one could directly work with $(x,y) \to (-t,t)$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have one more question. So we proved that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }f(u_{n})= cos(y)$. Does it show that the function is continuous? And what about  the point [0,0]? Sorry, I understood your solution, but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: $0 \in \mathbb{R}$ ?